# How to differentiate "pause" from "ended"

Tags: youtube-api

From what I can tell, when the user pauses the video, the onStateChange event will fire the "paused" event. However, when the video ends, the event first fires off the "paused" event, then fires off the "ended" event. What's the best way I can differentiate the former "paused" from the latter?

I'm trying to have it so that when the video ends, I load another one into the player. I need the "paused" event as I'm maintaining state in a Backbone model. Right now, the only way I can do it is to automatically change from paused to play when I get the "ended" event, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

What I'd expect that most people do is to listen for the `ENDED` event (like you're doing) and then make a call to `loadVideoById()`, which will take care of both loading a new video and starting playback.